# After creating RAID 1 can't connect to server

Tags: raid, software-raid

I have created RAID 1 array consisting of 2 devices(working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) :

```
mdadm --create /dev/md6 -l 1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda9 /dev/sdb6 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md6
mkdir /raid 
mdadm –detail –scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
update-initramfs -u
vim /etc/fstab  # next line is what I've put into the fstab file
/dev/md6    /raid       ext4        defaults    0  0
mount /raid
```

After the reboot I can't connect to my server(via ssh). 
Only when I boot into rescue mode and comment out fstab and mdadm.conf lines consisting info about md6, then I'm able to connect to my server.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md6
/dev/md6:
       Version : 1.2
 Creation Time : Sun Jan 26 14:52:22 2020
    Raid Level : raid1
    Array Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
 Used Dev Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
  Raid Devices : 2
 Total Devices : 2
   Persistence : Superblock is persistent

   Update Time : Sun Jan 26 17:06:17 2020
         State : clean 
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
 Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

          Name : popaja:6  (local to host popaja)
          UUID : 67d43386:09285115:0c33fcec:68fb2054
        Events : 17

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        9        0      active sync   /dev/sda9
   1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
```

This is how mdadm.conf looks like :

```
 # This configuration was auto-generated on Sat, 24 Nov 2018 16:01:31      +0000 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=e402909e:fd60a086:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=a0e2960f:72c3523c:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md5 UUID=d97cc04c:2812a744:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=e402909e:fd60a086:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=0.90 UUID=a0e2960f:72c3523c:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md5 metadata=0.90 UUID=d97cc04c:2812a744:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
ARRAY /dev/md6 metadata=1.2 name=popaja:6 UUID=67d43386:09285115:0c33fcec:68fb2054
```

As you can see I have more RAID devices and they have never bothered me. 
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I asked my server provider's customer service, and they fixed it but didn't explain how, except this message :

```
Diagnosis:
The server was found on the login without ping

Action:
Restarting the server in "bzimage" (OVH kernel)

Result:
Boot: OK
Ping: OK
Server on login
Services started
```

What does that mean ?

And the newly created RAID array /dev/md6 mounted automatically and works.